# How to put multiple existing graphs in a same plot?

Tags: r, plot, layout, graph

[This](https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) links explains how to plot multiple graphs in a same overall plot.

Now I have three existing graphs, `png1`, `png2`, `png3`.  I want a layout like below. How to achieve this?

[image]

---

Thank you very much for the answer, please remember to install the packages:

```
install.packages("png")
library(png)
install.packages("gridExtra")
library(gridExtra)
```

---

After using the `gridExtra`, I combined three graphs together. However, they had very low resolution. How can I make them at least the same resolution as the original ones?

[image]

Comment: Search for `mfrow` and you will find many examples.

Comment: but all the example I can see is to go through the plotting procedure, but I want to skip that. I just want the combining step.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918367/how-to-plot-with-a-png-as-background). It might get you what you are looking for together with my suggestion above.

Comment: could you please write an example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [`par`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.0/topics/par) or [`layout`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.0/topics/layout) function. See the examples here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.0/topics/layout

If you're interested in inserting image files into the plot, you'd use [`readPNG`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/png/versions/0.1-7/topics/readPNG) and [`rasterImage`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.5.0/topics/rasterImage) and/or the [grid raster functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.raster.html).

Example:

```
png1 = png::readPNG("png1.png")
png2 = png::readPNG("png2.png")
png3 = png::readPNG("png3.png")
images = list(png1, png2, png3)
grobs = lapply(images, grid::rasterGrob)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=grobs)
```

Comment: What form are your graphs in?

Comment: Try the gridExtra example.

Comment: I got low resolution (see the updated question), how to improve it?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366220/poor-resolution-of-raster-plot-when-output-to-file

Comment: The `maxpixels=1e8` option is in the `plot` function. But in my case, I do not have a plot function, how to address this?